# Error: Can't adapt type ExpressionWrapper when trying to get any value

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I was trying to show the distance between the user's coordinates and all coordinates in the database (student dormitories in this case) but for some reason getting the latitude and longitude of each entry gave an error as shown in the title.

Code:

```
class SohaeDormNearbyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.SohaeDormSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = models.SohaeDorm.objects.filter(is_active=True)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Get latitude and longitude from user
        lat1 = self.kwargs['user_latitude']
        lon1 = self.kwargs['user_longitude']
        lat2 = ExpressionWrapper(F('dorm_latitude'), output_field=FloatField())
        lon2 = ExpressionWrapper(F('dorm_longitude'), output_field=FloatField())
        dorm_id = ExpressionWrapper(F('id'), output_field=IntegerField())

        """
        STOP! Before running, add the following stored procedure!

        CREATE FUNCTION sohae_calculate_distance5(u_lat float, u_lng float,
        d_id integer) RETURNS float AS $$
        SELECT (6367*acos(cos(radians(u_lat))
           *cos(radians(dorm_latitude))
           *cos(radians(dorm_longitude)
           -radians(u_lng))
           +sin(radians(u_lat))*sin(radians(dorm_latitude))))
           AS distance FROM sohaegeum_sohaedorm WHERE id = d_id
        $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
        """

        return models.SohaeDorm.objects.annotate(
            # Add the distance in KM as an attribute
            distance=RawSQL(
                "SELECT sohae_calculate_distance5(%s, %s, %s) AS distance",
                (lat1, lon1, dorm_id)
            )
        ).filter(is_active=True)
```

Traceback gave me the following:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/sohaegeum/dorms/nearby/8.238479/124.243347/

Django Version: 2.0.6
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_auth',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'rest_auth.registration',
 'api',
 'sohaegeum']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (can't adapt type 'ExpressionWrapper') was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  480.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in get
  201.         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
  48.         return Response(serializer.data)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  765.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  262.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  683.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  272.         self._fetch_all()

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1068.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /api/v1/sohaegeum/dorms/nearby/8.238479/124.243347/
Exception Value: can't adapt type 'ExpressionWrapper'
```

Even getting the ID of each dormitory entry using the F() method also results in the same error.

UPDATE: I forgot I used a wrong function when I originally posted this.

Comment: I think `ExpressionWrapper` can't be used with `RawSQL`

Comment: @JPG I didn't know that. Still waiting for a workaround for this to work as expected.

Comment: what is the `calculate_distance` function here? Where is the definition?

Comment: @JPG I was putting the wrong function when I initially posted this. Changed.

Comment: how does it look like, the `sohae_calculate_distance5` function?

Comment: The `sohae_calculate_distance5` is a function coded in the database. It takes three parameters: the user's latitude, longitude, and the dormitory's ID (primary key).